# AngularJS, PHP MySQL implementation returns PHP code instead of query result

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm able to read values from a database using PHP. And then I'm trying to execute this PHP through AngularJS controller.

**view1.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('view1/view1.php').then(successCallback, errorCallback);

    function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.songs = response.data;
    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}]);
```

**view1.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "songs"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sel = mysqli_query($con, "select * from description");
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
    $data[] = array("artist" => $row['artist'], "key" => 
$row['song_key'], "beat" => $row['beat']);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

**view1.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp.view1" ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
    {{songs}}
</div>
```

This is the code I've done and this returns not the db data. It returns the exact same PHP code for `{{songs}}`.

Comment: your issue isn't clear, what do you means by : "not returns the db data" ? could you show us what is actually returned and what is expected ? 

What's also the original data of `$scope.songs` ?

Comment: I wanted to fetch db data and print those data in html. But `{{songs}}` returns the `view1.php` code.

Comment: @codebot what's the output when you directly access `localhost/view1/view1.php`?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/view1/view1.php`. This is just downloading the file

Comment: @codebot are you certain that the http port is `8000`, not `80`?

Comment: I started the app with `npm start`. So the port is 8000

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you are requesting PHP server (port 80) from the default npm server (port 8000), try changing `get()` request parameter to :

```
$http.get('http://localhost/view1/view1.php').then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

So it will not going through npm server.

Comment: This hits the debugger on `errorCallback`. `error.data` is null

Comment: What is the output when you change `$scope.songs = response.data;` to `$scope.songs = response;` ?

Comment: and when you call directly http://localhost/view1/view1.php what's happen ? in your network what's the status code for your request ?